# Issue with stretching Jumbotron across page (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm trying to make the jumbotron on [our website](http://www.globalstudentsquare.org/welcome/) stretch across the entire page. ()

We're using visual composer, so I can access the CSS just fine.

I've already tried forcing width and floating the sidebar, but I suspect that JavaScript is automatically changing it.

Comment: Can you add a little more information? It looks like it is working fine for me, and stretches the full width of the window.

Comment: Oops - wrong link. Added the right link!